# How can i disable nuxt / redirect

Tags: node.js, nuxt.js

My nuxt application redirect all url that ends with /
ex:`localhost/list/` redirect to `localhost/list`

Can i disable this redirection?

Thanks!

Comment: please share your `nuxt.config.js` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your `trailingSlash` config in router of your Nuxt app.
to do this, change(or add if does not exists) `nuxt.config.js` file like this:

```js
export default {
    router: {
      trailingSlash: false
    },
}
```

### Redirect slash to no-slash

If you want to redirect all trailing slashes to no-slash routes follow the instruction below:

First install `@nuxtjs/redirect-module` using **NPM**:

```
npm i @nuxtjs/redirect-module
```

Add below blocks to `nuxt.config.js`:

```js
{
    modules: [
        '@nuxtjs/redirect-module'
    ],
    redirect: [
        {
           // eslint-disable-next-line
           from: '(?!^\/$|^\/[?].*$)(.*\/[?](.*)$|.*\/$)',
           to: (from, req) => {
           const base = req._parsedUrl.pathname.replace(/\/$/, '');
           const search = req._parsedUrl.search;
           return base + (search != null ? search : '');
        },
    ]
}
```

Example: `localhost/list/` will redirect to `localhost/list`

Comment: trailingSlash does not solved my problem, but this answer helped me to find out i had wrong redirect in config